# LINQ to XML Search regardless of lower or uppercase string

Tags: c#, xml, linq

My example returns data from an XML file based off of whats entered into a text box. The problem is if the XML file contains Jon and I type Jon, the the results from the XML file are displayed. But, if I type jon with a lowercase j, no data is returned. How could I resolve that problem? I provided my code snippet below:

```
 var query = 
    from r in document.Descendants("Employee")
    where ((string)r.Element("FirstName").Value).Contains(txtSearch.Text)
    select new
    {
        FirstName = r.Element("FirstName").Value,
        Age = r.Element("Age").Value
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to use `ToLower()`

```
var query = 
from r in document.Descendants("Employee")
where ((string)r.Element("FirstName").Value) 
     .ToLower()
     .Contains(txtSearch.Text)
     .ToLower()
select new
{
    FirstName = r.Element("FirstName").Value,
    Age = r.Element("Age").Value
};
```

Another more fancier way is to roll-your-own extension method

```
public static bool ContainsIgnoreCase(this string str, string value) 
            => str?.IndexOf(value, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0;
```

or

```
public static bool ContainsEx(this string str, string value, StringComparison comparison = StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) 
            => str?.IndexOf(value, comparison) >= 0;
```

Comment: Thanks, I greatly appreciate the assist